# What happens if you wire two solar panels in series and parallel at the same time?

Tags: power, solar

Will anything bad happen?
Or is it safe.

Comment: Parallel wiring will be likely bad. The two panels won't give exactly the same voltage... it serial is imho okay. Hopefully someone will give more details in an answer.

Comment: in series **and** parallel **at the same time**.  Not possible.  Please clarify.

Comment: The EcoFlow 50 watt panels have a port on them to series connect two panels, and each panel also has an outport port which can fed into a parallel connector, so it would be possible to do it, not going to try it, just want to know what would happen.

No MC4 connectors like you might be imagining.

Comment: All barrel jack connectors

Comment: Just because they have series **AND** parallel connections, does not mean they can be connected.  Best case: nothing.  Worst case: damage to both panels.

Answer (score 2):

It is physically impossible to wire *anything* in series and parallel *at the same time*. It is possible to arrange a set of connectors which will allow one to *choose* whether the components are in series or parallel but this is a different thing.

Your homework is to draw the circuit diagram for a pair of components that are in series, and then add the wires necessary to put them in parallel at the same time. Then, reduce the resulting diagram and try writing Ohm's law for it.

Comment: I am curious, what would happen if different solar cells with different illumination were wired in parallel? Is the final voltage you see the simple weighted average of all the voltages of the cells? Would the weighting be based on the area of the cells? If they were wired in series, the final voltage is just the sum of all the cells' voltages?

Comment: @MeEngineerTrustMe What would happen if you put two batteries of different pontials in parallel?

Comment: the higher voltage battery would run the lower voltage battery backwards.